# componentWillUnmount should be called before componentDidMount of the incoming component, isn't it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a base class in React which is getting extended by child classes:

```
export default class extends Base {
 ... 
}
```

Now, in order to efficiently subscribe to events and automatically unsubscribe by the time the component is getting unmounted, I am using a method called subscribe and method called unsubscribe in the Base class (which is the parent) to handle this.

Now everything is working good, until I move from the same page, to the same page, but with different ID in props.

In such a case, what happening is that the joining component did mount functions are getting executed BEFORE the leaving component functions. For example see this console:

[image]

The first *mounted to* console is the first page that was loaded.
Then the second *mounted to* is the new component that is getting joined. 
And the last *unmounted from* is getting executed from the first component that is leaving.

In such a case, React subscribes to events in the joining component and then just unsubscribe them, because of the unmount of the OLD component.

I need to be sure that the old component is clearing all of its subscribes and then initiate the new component. OR - I need to disable unsubscribing for events if the new component is the same component but with different props.

How to fix this issue?